# How to dynamically add a code behind for button

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Button bn = new Button();
bn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(560, 350);
bn.Name = "btnDelete";
bn.Text = "Delete";
bn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 50);
myTabPage.Controls.Add(bn);
```

I have positioned the button, what property would I use to add code behind the button?

Comment: Also worth reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty easy:

```
bn.Click += MyClick;

...

private void MyClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```

Here you're registering a click event and specify the code that runs when the event fires.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some stuff to prep the button on the form (referenced by `this` in the example, taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53zat12.aspx.)

```
private void AddButtons()
{
   // Suspend the form layout and add two buttons.
   this.SuspendLayout();
   Button buttonOK = new Button();
   buttonOK.Location = new Point(10, 10);
   buttonOK.Size = new Size(75, 25);
   buttonOK.Text = "OK";

   this.Controls.Add(buttonOK);
   this.ResumeLayout();
}
```

There is really no "code behind" -- the Button is the object, use it as you wish. Presumably you want to subscribe to the click event:

```
bn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bnClickListener);

private void bnClickListener(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Stuff to do when clicked.
}
```